# Translation of literary "non-sequitur"

Tags: translation

Is there an equivalent of the literary device known as a "non-sequitur" in English, or at least some kind of translation of it? This is not to be confused with the non-sequitur logical fallacy (where one logical argument does not follow another).

> **From Wiktionary:**
>
> [*non sequitur*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non_sequitur#English)
>
> A kind of pun that uses a change of word, subject, or meaning to make a joke of the listener’s expectation.
>
> > “A fool and his money are soon ***partying***.” ([Steven Wright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Wright))
> >
> > (Expected word: *parting*)

Comment: How about giving an example of a literary device known as a "non-sequitur" in English to differentiate it from the non-sequitur logical fallacy (where one logical argument does not follow another)? TQ

Comment: There's now 5 answers, and I still have no idea what a literary non-sequitur is.  The incoming answers seem to ignore the "not to be confused with the non-sequitur logical fallacy" part of the question.  I think it's fair to say the question is unclear.

Comment: Please amend your answers, everyone. Plenty of examples of this are found in traditional dialogue in the literary arts, exemplified in the PRC Chinese New Year Gala.

Comment: I've deleted my "answer" while waiting for clarification as per my earlier comment.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't find this question unclear in the slightest. Questions asked on this site are often met with a lot of 答非所问 answers. I have even frequently seen answers that don't even being to answer the actual question asked upvoted above answers that actually address the question. Becky says that people are "ignore"[ing] sections of the question and I believe that is really the true issue.

Answer (score 2):

**不当的推论**

[超现实幽默](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%B6%85%E7%8E%B0%E5%AE%9E%E5%B9%BD%E9%BB%98)

> 条目“不当的推论”尚未创建，可参考英语维基百科的对应页面：Non sequitur (literary device)。

Answer (score 0):

Nah, non sequitur means a statement that does not have any connection with what was said before. Common practice is to explain its meaning: 未根据前提的推理；与前述无关的推论 etc. It looks like that nobody seriously translates it.

Let me have a try: 不因之论；所论不因

因，顺、承、连接也。So 不因之论 literally means: a statement that dosen't follow (what was said before)

Answer (score 0):

If I use traditional Chinese to write this I will write 語無倫次. It means someone speaks without conventional logic. For example: 他喝醉酒後講話語無倫次。

Answer (score -1):

How about:

驴唇不对马嘴: incongruous